# Every Banach space is connected?

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, connectedness

Here is what I thought about this statement.

Let $V$ be a Banach space over real numbers. Consider $x\in V$ and $A_x=\{ax : a\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

**Claim:** $A_x$ is connected for each $x$ in $V$.

If we prove the above claim then we are done since $0 \in \cap_{x} A_x $ which is nonempty. So $\cup_{x} A_x = V$ will be connected

Suppose $A_x$ is not connected then there are open sets $G'$ and $H'$ such that $A_x = G' \cup H'$ where $G'$ and $H'$ are disjoint. Clearly $G'$ and $H'$ must contain scalar multiple of $x$. So there exist $G$ and $H$ such that $G' = \{ax : a \in G\}$ and $H' =\{ax : a \in H\}$

What I figured out is $G \cup H = \mathbb{R}$ and $G \cap H = \phi$. If I show $G$ and $H$ are open then we get a contradiction because $\mathbb{R}$ is connected.

I am not able to show $G$ and $H$ are open. Is my approach wrong? How do I use completeness of $V$? Or is there a Banach space which is not connected?

Any alternative approaches are also helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the continuous surjective map $\Bbb R \to A_x, a\mapsto ax$. $\Bbb R$ is connected and the continuous image of a connected set is connected.

Also note that it's also easy to show that a Banach space (or indeed, any topological vector space) is path-connected directly: Let $v \in V$, then we have a path connecting $0$ and $v$ given by $[0,1] \to V, a \mapsto av$.

Comment: Are you using the fact that $V$ is Banach space anywhere? Does this hold for any normed space?

Comment: @mathee_z the only thing I am using is that scalar multiplication is continuous. This holds for any topological vector space, in particular for normed spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Put $f : \mathbb R\to A_x$, $f(a) = ax$. Then $f$ is continuous and $G = f^{-1}(G')$ is open in $\mathbb R$.